# Basic div; container and wrapper

Tags: html, css

I just started to make HTML, i need a container with `100%` width and a wrapper with 980px and center aligned.
I just pasted my code in JSFIDDLE.
What's wrong with the code?

```
#section-1{
    background: #f7f3ed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 30px 0 100px 0;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
#section-1 h2{
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.wrapper-1{
    text-align: center;
    width: 980px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
}

<div id="section-1" class="wrapper-1">
        <h2>Hey this is just a test</h2>    
        </div>
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9tzNu/)

Comment: What is exactly you question? Do you want apply vertical centering?

Comment: *i need a container with 100% width and a wrapper with 980px *  I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your #section-1 shouldn't have a `max-width:1300px;` if you want 100% width, so remove that.

Or not, if you want it that way. What does really matter are the following below.

Your `.wrapper-1` should have `margin:0 auto;`

That makes your `.wrapper-1` div centered horizontally.

Also your HTML should be

```
<div id="section-1">
    <div class="wrapper-1">
        <h2>Hey this is just a test</h2>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only having one element which you both assign an id and a class. You need a section and inside the section a wrapper like so:

```
<div id="section-1">
    <div class="wrapper-1">
        <h2>Hey this is just a test</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

For demonstration I changed the width to `280px` of the wrapper, change it to whatever you want. To center block elements horizontally you need to give them an auto margin:

```
.wrapper-1{
    text-align: center;
    width: 280px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[See the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9tzNu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty standard problem. You want a wrapper and a container, but you're trying to do both with the same div. You need 1 div for container, 1 div for wrapper.

Here is a solution for you (be carefull with "width:100%" and borders) :
http://jsfiddle.net/9tzNu/3/

```
<div id="container">
       <div id="wrapper">
        <h2>Hey this is just a test</h2>    
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#container{
    background: #f7f3ed;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin:0 auto ;
    padding: 30px 0 100px 0;
}

#wrapper{
    text-align: center;
    width: 980px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    margin:0 auto ;
}
```

Here you have standard pattern that can help you starting a project :
http://www.alsacreations.com/static/gabarits/liste.html